# Read PCL is too slow

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pcl reader is too slow. Is there another function to load pcd files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103006/read-pcl--is-too-slow/) by [mike_87](https://answers.ros.org/users/8996/mike_87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default pcl reader is the recommended one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0